# R: Adding qualitative data with non numerical values to a plot loop

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a sample `data.frame` with 'normal data' which produces in this case 2 plots by groups (here groups are split by `ID`). Below you can find my code to do this:

```
# Normal Dataframe
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259),YEAR=c(1959,1960,1960,1961,1961,1963,1963,1965,2004,2007,2007,2009,2009,2010,2010,2011,2011,2014),VALUE=c(0,-6,-6,-16,-16,-31,-31,-54,0,-9,-9,-24,-24,-69,-69,-92,-92,-132))
xy$ID <-paste(xy$ID, ".png", sep = "") # Add .png Fileextension
ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID']) # index split by ID

### PLOT
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  png(names(ind[i]), width=3358, height=2329, res=300)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
       type='n',
       main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]", 
       ylab="Length change [m]")  
  # plot axis
  axis(1, at = seq(1000,2030,10), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3) 
  # plot points and lines
  points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
  points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=1,   pch=21, bg='white')  
  dev.off() 
}
```

This works all fine but I also have qualitative data which I'd like to display in the plots. The (sample) `data.frame` looks like this:

```
data_qual <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME2"),ID=c(47,47,259),SURVEY_YEAR=c(1961,1964,2010), REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1960,1962,2006),VALUE_SURYEAR=c("-X","ST","+x"),VALUE_REFYEAR=c("-X","ST","+x"))

data_qual
  NAME  ID SURVEY_YEAR REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE_SURYEAR VALUE_REFYEAR
1 NAME1  47        1961           1960            -X            -X
2 NAME1  47        1964           1962            ST            ST
3 NAME2 259        2010           2006            +x            +x
```

How could I plot a line from the `REFERENCE_YEAR` to the `SURVEY_YEAR` and above the line in the middle the qualitative `VALUE_` (doesn't matter if taken from `VALUE_SURYEAR` or `VALUE_REFYEAR` since they are always the same) and incorporate it into my plot loop? Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this?

Here is a graphical approximation of what I am attempting to do for the first plot:
[image]

Is there I way I could incorporate this into my plot code? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

It is basically your code, but I made a new column `ID2` for the ID +png name. I then made a sub-loop with a `lines()` function and a `text()` function to add the lines and labels.

```
xy <-data.frame( NAME = c("NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME1", 
"NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2"),
 ID=c(47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259),
YEAR=c(1959,1960,1960,1961,1961,1963,1963,1965,2004,2007,2007,2009,2009,2010,2010,2011,2011,2014),
VALUE=c(0,-6,-6,-16,-16,-31,-31,-54,0,-9,-9,-24,-24,-69,-69,-92,-92,-132))


xy$ID2 <-paste(xy$ID, ".png", sep = "") # Add .png Fileextension
ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID']) # index split by ID

data_qual <- data.frame( NAME= c("NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME2"), 
    ID=c(47,47,259), SURVEY_YEAR=c(1961,1964,2010),
     REFERENCE_YEAR=c(1960,1962,2006),
     VALUE_SURYEAR=c("-X","ST","+x"),VALUE_REFYEAR=c("-X","ST","+x"))

### PLOT
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  png(names(ind[i]), width=3358, height=2329, res=300)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
     type='n',
     main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
     xlab="Time [Years]", 
     ylab="Length change [m]")  
 # plot axis
 axis(1, at = seq(1000,2030,10), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3) 
 # plot points and lines
 points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
 points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=1,   pch=21, bg='white')  
 for(j in 1 : nrow(data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),])) {
lines(
  x=c(data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),]$REFERENCE_YEAR[j], data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),]$SURVEY_YEAR[j] ), 
  y=c(min(ind[[i]][,"VALUE"]), min(ind[[i]][,"VALUE"]) )
)
text(
  x=mean(c(data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),]$REFERENCE_YEAR[j], data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),]$SURVEY_YEAR[j])),
  y=min(ind[[i]][,"VALUE"]+3),
  labels=as.character(data_qual[data_qual$ID==names(ind[i]),]$VALUE_SURYEAR[j]) 
)
}
 dev.off()  

 }
}
```

Comment: thank you. this is what I've been looking for! there seems to be one line missing though in order to work: ind2 <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID2'])

Comment: @redshoe I think I just changed `ind` to `ind2` by accident. I changed it back, so I now I think you can just use `ind`. Sorry about that.

Comment: I seem to be running into problems with your solution, eventhough it should work as far as I understand your code. I posted a new question with some of my actual data (not sample data) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733969/r-adding-qualitative-data-with-non-numerical-values-to-a-plot-loop-continued It would be great if you could have a look at it? Thank you!